# Convert multiple same Rows as Column headers

Tags: python, pandas

This is my table:

```py
pivot_notNone = pivot[pivot['GHG'].notna()]
pivot_notNone.head(10)
```

|  | UOM | GHG Conversion Factor 2022 | Unit | GHG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tonnes | 3029.260000 | kg | CO2 |
| 2 | tonnes | 2.250000 | kg | CH4 |
| 3 | tonnes | 1.800000 | kg | N2O |
| 5 | litres | 1.742960 | kg | CO2 |
| 6 | litres | 0.001290 | kg | CH4 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 8032 | tonnes | 105.669500 | kg | CO2 |

[4312 rows × 4 columns]

I would like to column names as `N2O`, `CO2` and `CH4` and their values should be `GHG Conversion Factor Values`. But when I tried this (using Pandas)

```py
a = pivot_notNone.pivot(columns=['GHG'],values='GHG Conversion Factor 2022')
a
```

I got the following result:

| GHG | CH4 | CO2 | N2O |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NaN | 3029.260000 | NaN |
| 2 | 2.25000 | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | NaN | NaN | 1.8 |
| 5 | NaN | 1.742960 | NaN |
| 6 | 0.00129 | NaN | NaN |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 8032 | NaN | 1105.669500 | NaN |
| 8033 | NaN | 0.199021 | NaN |
| 8034 | NaN | 679.986742 | NaN |
| 8035 | NaN | 0.199021 | NaN |
| 8036 | NaN | 0.115069 | NaN |

[4312 rows × 3 columns]

My expectation is:

| UOM | Unit | CH4 | CO2 | N2O |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| tonnes | kg | 225.000 | 3.029.260.000 | 1.8 |
| litres | kg | 0.00129 | 1.742.960 | 11.105.669 |
| kWh | kg | ... | ... | ... |
| tonnes | kg | ... | ... | .. |
| ... | kg | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Please [do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), add the information as text (within code fences etc.) instead.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve your goal by using `pivot` or `pivot_table`: To get _"full"_ rows (without `NaN`) you need a couple of columns that act as unifying index and draw the values in the rows. But you don't have that.

Comment: In your expected output, you have two rows that have the same values for UOM and Unit (tonnes / kg) - rows 1 and 4. What should be different about these two rows? Or should they be exactly the same?

Comment: @scotscotmcc That was the point I was trying to make, probably too convoluted :) I suspect there is some regularity in the data (in the `GHG` column) and that they could chop the `df` in pieces, transpose them, and then concat the parts togehter (roughly). But without further knowledge about the input data there's no way to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if we assume that your starting data has sort of groups of 3 rows of related data, we can maybe get away with adding a new grouping field to group them, and then we can pivot using that as well.

```py
df['new_grouping_field'] = df.index // 3 # this gives the whole-number piece of the division,
# so rows 0-2 will get a 0, rows 3-5 will get a 1, etc. Does require that the
# index is numbers, which it should be
df.pivot(
  columns='GHG',
  values='GHG Conversion Factor 2022',
  index=['new_grouping_field','UOM','Unit']
)
```

Comment: That’s a good idea.